# Statistic binomial dist

Tags: calculus, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, binomial-theorem

[image]

Can you help me to solve this question pls, I consider that I Will use binomial distrıbutıon but I couldnt

Comment: Why do you want to use the binomial distribution ? If I understand the exercise right, then there is a probability of 40% of picking a plain truffle.

Comment: Actually I am confused. I am not süre whether I should use bınomial or not.

Comment: In this exercise the binomial distribution doesn´t play a role.

Comment: What is a Godiva shop?

Comment: Chocolate company, so How I can solve?

Comment: How can I solve c part can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ad c)**

You have to assume, that the prepacked bag contains great many cockies. In this case the probability to pick three black truffles in a row is approximately $0.2\cdot 0.2 \cdot 0.2 =0.2^3=0.008=0.8\text{%}$. 
This is only a approximation.

Let´s say, that a prepacked bag contains 1000 cockies and 200 of them are black truffles. The probability to pick three black truffles in a row  is then $\frac{200}{1000}\cdot \frac{199}{999} \cdot \frac{198}{998}=0.007904...=0.7904...\text{%}$

The more cockies are in the bag, the better is the approximation. The approximation has to be done, because we don´t know how many cockies are in one bag.

Comment: Thnk you :) @calculus

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

a) The probability is 0.4. I hope there is no need to discuss it anymore.

b) Again very simple. The answer is 0.4 + 0.2 = 0.6.

c) You have to realize what is the probability of three independent events. According to the definition of independence, it is product of the events. In your case it is 0.2*0.2*0.2 = 0.008.

Comment: You are welcome.